# Longtable \hline at top produces \noalign error

Tags: longtable, hline

I got a longtable for my project with the caption at the bottom. Creating the table alone works perfectly fine, but as soon as I try to add a toprule it throws a `` ! Misplaced \noalign.\hline ->\noalign{\ifnum 0=`}\fi \penalty \@M \futurelet \@let@token \LT@@h... \hline ``
error. In this case I added a toprule with the `\hline` command, but same happens when I use booktabs and `\toprule`.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,parskip=half, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{ |p{90mm} | p{30mm}|}[h] 
    %\hline %uncomment this hline to produce error  
    \textbf{Kommentar} & \textbf{Versuchsgruppe (Gesicht)} \\
    \hline
    \lipsum[1-1] & animiert \\
    \hline
    \lipsum[2-2] & abstrakt \\
    \hline
    \lipsum[3-3] & abstrakt \\
    \hline
    \lipsum[4-4] & abstrakt \\
    \hline
    \lipsum[5-5] & echt \\
    \hline
    \caption{Die in der qualitativen Analyse betrachteten Kommentare (formatiert)} \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

How can I solve this? All other tables in my document have a line at the top, but they don't use longtable. I really need this line for consistency.
I saw that some people struggled with that due to `\nopagebreak` or additional line space, but my table has neither of such.

EDIT: As suggested in the comments I removed `\centering`, but the error still exists. It is not the only issue.

Comment: remove `\centering` it is doing nothing useful and generating the error

Comment: Remove that `[h]`, `longtable` does not support an option in that location, additionally `\centering` inside `longtable` does nothing

Comment: You would also get the same error in `tabular` if you use `\centering` before `\hline` there is nothing `longtable` specific here.

Comment: @daleif You are right, [h] triggered the issue. :) You want to post the answer or should I just do it? :)

Comment: It is both, you're not allowed to have anything before a `\hline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors here

1. `\begin{longtable}{ |p{90mm} | p{30mm}|}[h]` should loose the `[h]`
2. The original question started the `longtable` contents with a `\centering` which would not do much, but is nonetheless not allowed just before a `\hline`.